# .....in (the) university?

Tags: articles

I believe the following to be correct:

What did you do in university?

My student, however, asked me why it has no 'the'. I thought I had better ask folks here for the answer.

Comment: Article usage hereabouts is very idiosyncratic, and different trends can sometimes be seen on different sides of the Atlantic. In this case, 'in university' means in the establishment (/ on your course, etc): the container metaphor. Compare 'at home / school / work ...'. 'Some of us are at/in university now.' 'In the university' often means 'part of the university infrastructure': 'We have a lot of Elbonians in the University'.

Comment: Note also that "in university" is almost unknown in the US.

Comment: @phoog.  Unused, not unknown in the sense that the meaning would be unclear.  We're far more likely to get hung up on *writing an exam.* (Looking at you, Canada)

Answer (score 1):

As phoog points out, Americans never say "in university," though others (British?) would.  We could say "What did you do at the university?" but that question does not suggest you are enrolled; it could be when you visited the university for a day, or while you were employed by the university.  To say the same thing, we'd say "What did you do in college?"  Or if we're professors, we might say "What did you do in undergraduate?" or "What did you do in graduate school?"

In general, we'd use "the" if it's about being in a location ("What happened at the courthouse?") but not if it's a time or a process ("What happened during court?" or "Who did you see at church?").  I'd say Americans think of "university" as a place, but not a process; but "college" is both.  Go figure.